# C# Pdf Attachment damaged when sent to yahoo mail addresses

Tags: c#, email, pdf

I'm trying to send an Email with an attached PDF file. When I send it to any other mail provider it works just fine, but when I send it to a yahoo email address, the receiver gets a damaged pdf file. The exact message it gives is:

> Adobe Reader could not open 'Filename.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Because the other email providers were working, I used the following code specifically for yahoo addresses.

```
if (thisItem.EmailAddress.ToUpper().Contains("YAHOO")){
  ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
  contentType.CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
  Attachment theFile = new Attachment(attachmentPath, contentType);
  theFile.Name = theFile.Name.Replace("_","");

  mm.Attachments.Add(theFile);
}
```

I've tried a variety of CharSets on the ContentType, hoping that would fix something, no change. I also tried different TransferEncodings on theFile, also no fix. I read somewhere that the file name could cause problems if it had special characters so I removed all the underscores in the name, all that's left is some letters and numbers. I'm not sure what else to try at this point. Any suggestions?

Comment: The "encoding" is not applied to the file name but to its *contents*. And changing the 'encoding' of a PDF -- a *binary* file -- is not a good idea. Try find out how to set the Content encoding to Binary (my C# skills are nonexistent, but see for ex. http://www.dart.com/help/ptmlnet/Dart.Mail~Dart.Mail.TransferEncoding.html).

Comment: Are you generating the PDF too?  If so, have you tried with some 3rd party PDF files off of the net, instead?  The problem could be in the generation rather than the sending.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am able to download and open pdf files if I run the project locally but I cannot open the files if I receive the emails from the production azurewebiste. Nobody has a solution for that?